# IBDesignable controls and Cocoa bindings

Tags: cocoa, binding

Having created an IBDesignable control for use in Interface Builder, it looks like Cocoa bindings are only available for its "Hidden" property and Tooltip parameter. Am I missing something here? Is it not possible to bind the control's value?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. You could try `[self exposeBinding:@"bindingValue"]`, but I'm not sure whether that would work.

Comment: What is the Cocoa superclass of the control?

Comment: The superclass is NSControl.

Comment: And the self.exposeBinding(selector) method does not seem to be available.

Comment: @jdobres `exposeBinding` is a class method, you call it from `+initialize`. BTW that's objective-c, I don't do swift.

Comment: @jdobres https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSKeyValueBindingCreation_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/exposeBinding:

Answer (score 0):

The two bindings exposed by `NSControl` are in fact inherited from `NSView` - `NSControl` itself exposes no additional bindings. Apple provides information about all available bindings in its [Introduction to Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/CocoaBindingsRef.html). If you want to use bindings within your control you should consider adding more specialized subviews to the control (e.g. `NSTextField`, `NSImageView`) and exploiting their bindings.